# How I can Take Screen shot from TMediaPlayerControl in FM2?

Tags: delphi, firemonkey, delphi-xe3

For doing this action I use below code:

```
procedure TForm4.Button2Click(Sender: TObject);
begin
  MediaPlayerControl1.MakeScreenshot.SaveToFile('c:\temp\e.bmp');
end;
```

When this code runs bitmap saved to file; but It is a black Image all of the time.
I am trying for solving this problem.
please help me.

Comment: you'd probably seek a way to extract and capture picture frame via DirectShow interface using DSPack components. MediaPlayerControl is probably wrapper around 1993 VideoForWindows API, which is long obsolete.

Comment: @Arioch'The No, MediaPlayerControl is a wrapper around DirectShow on Windows and QuickTime on Mac.

Comment: @iamjoosy then all DS-based players i saw (like Media Player classic or Delphi-written KMPlayer and probably-Delphi Sasami2000) - they all used terms "Extract frame" or "Grab frame" - and i think that does have direct equivalence in Direct X API

Comment: @Arioch'The Typically the way to extract a frame in DirectShow  is to insert a "Sample grabber" filter in the filter graph. However, not having Delphi XE3 I cannot comment on how they implemented it there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

MakeScreenshot is actually a method of [FMX.Types.TControl](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/XE3/en/FMX.Types.TControl.MakeScreenshot) and a such designed to draw the content of an underlying window to a bitmap. Since DirectShow uses [Video Renderer Filters](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd407349%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) that in most cases use DirectDraw and overlay surfaces to render video frames, the MakeScreenshot method never "sees" the video frames - hence the black bitmaps. It seems there is no built in way into TMediaPlayer to access the video frames, like it is forseen in the [SampleBufferToBitmap](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/XE3/en/FMX.Media.TVideoCaptureDevice.SampleBufferToBitmap) method of a [TVideoCaptureDevice](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/XE3/en/FMX.Media.TVideoCaptureDevice)